# Unable test uploading of files in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am a newbie to Rails and Rspec. My spec file has a scenario as follows

```
scenario "Admin creates a new Specification ", js: true do
  sign_in_with admin_user
  visit "/general_docs/new"
  fill_in "general_doc_name", :with => "Specifications1"
  set_live_search_select_value_for('#general_doc_course_id', Course.first.id)
  select "Specifications", :from=> "general_doc[doc_type]"
  select  "student", :from=> "general_doc[user_role_id]"
  check "general_doc_active"
  path = "/Home/workspace/ums/spec/fixtures/files/demo.png"
  attach_file "multiple_file_uploader_url", path
  click_button "Create General doc"
expect(page).to have_content "Document was successfully created."
  end
```

I am getting following error.
Failure/Error: attach_file "multiple_file_uploader_url", path
     Capybara::FileNotFound:
       cannot attach file, /Home/workspace/ums/spec/fixtures/files/demo.png does not exist

But the path which I have given is correct.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your **path** variable by following

```
path = File.join('spec/fixtures', 'files', 'demo.png')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but the problem still exists. It gives the same error. I double checked the file path, (i,e, file is present in the specified path).

Comment: Hi I changed argument for attach_file from "multiple_file_uploader_url" to "multiplefileuploader", and changed the path of the file from 'spec/fixtures' to 'spec' but now I am getting a different error: =>  The error is as follows   Failure/Error: attach_file "multiplefileuploader", File.join('spec', 'demo.png')
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find file field "multiplefileuploader"

Comment: answerer missed the files directory, it should be: `path = File.join('spec/fixtures', 'files', 'demo.png')`

Comment: Yes, I have missed it